# Delay between bindService() and onBind() when starting a Service

Tags: android, binding, android-fragments, android-activity, android-service

I'm facing a strange problem with my app. I have a LocationService that runs in the background. The way I manage its lifecycle is:

1. In `onResume`, every activity uses `bindService(intent,serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)` like that the service is automatically created when needed.
2. In `onStop`, every activity uses `unbindService(serviceConnection)`
3. This works because when switching activities, the new `Activity` `onResume` is called before the old `Activity` `onStop` method

The problem I have is, lets say I start from the home screen and I launch the app with an Activity that has a fragment in it. The order of the function call is as follows

1. Activity `onCreate` --> `setContentView` is called here
2. Activity `onResume` --> here `bindService` is called and should create the `Service`
3. **Fragment `onResume`**
4. Service `onBind` method is called

My question is why is there a something else between my `bindService`and `onBind` calls?? I have a feeling this has something to do with threading issues.

Comment: The delay is an expected behaviour, as the bindService() is indeed an asynchronous call, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802456/when-exactly-onserviceconnected-for-bounded-service-will-be-called/10807311#10807311) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, it does not say that it is an asynchronous call in the documentation, that's why I was confused. Do you want to put it up as an answer?

Comment: Hey, granted I was unnecessarily verbose, but didn't I say the same thing (and before york's comment was posted, I believe).  I'm not looking to get the bounty, but if you think my answer is wrong then plz comment to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this isn't a very good answer, but why wouldn't there be something else between your `bindService()` and `onBind()` calls?  You seem to be assuming that when you call bind the system will immediately create and start your service, and no such guarantee is provided.

You haven't indicated whether yours is an `IntentService`, or just a regular Service, and this might affect the speed with which your service is launched, but my answer would be the same.

Also, I'm assuming that your `ServiceConnection` object is called, as expected, sometime after your service's `onBind()` returns.

I say this not based on having read anything definitive, but because I had a similar experience: I was surprised and annoyed at how long it took before my service was created and my `ServiceConnection` was called, even though I returned from the service's onBind very quickly.  (My fragments needed data from the service to create the initial UI so any delay in the creation of the service meant a delay in displaying the initial UI to the user.)

In the end I settled upon launching my service using an Intent rather then a bind, e.g.

```
Intent si = new Intent( this, com.company.MyService.class );
si.setAction( MyService.SVC_BIND );
startService( si );
```

I then sent `MyService.SVC_UNBIND` in place of calling unbind.  When I received the UNBIND intent in my service I cleanup and then call `stopSelf()`.  These are user actions - I just named them for how I'm using them.

I believe this was faster, but looking back upon my comments from that code I don't have any specifics. Note that this meant no `ServiceConnection`, but I'm making some direct calls from the activities into the service, and using `LocalBroadcastManager` a fair bit.

Another option to consider (in order that your service be started more quickly, if that is your goal here??) is to launch it in `Appliction.onCreate()`, rather then waiting for `Activity.onResume()`.  All of these options make it necessary to do some extra work to determine when to stop the service, compared to your current, normal, scheme where that is taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my issue was using `android:process` attribute for `<service>` element within Android Manifest, which is supposed to improve performance, but in reallity, maybe it does once the service is running, but it takes a very long while to reach `onCreate()` (and so also to reach `onBind()`). For me it was taking minutes. Now Apps and services run smooth and as expected.

More info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element